# How to configure deployment servlet contexts using jersey test framework

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, junit, jersey

So I am trying to use JUnit to test my APIs exposed via Jersey 2. I have it on a Tomcat server which is using the following context.xml to connect to an Oracle DB:

**/META-INF/context.xml**:

```
<Context>

  <Resource name="jdbc/DeliveryDB"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            username="usernamee"
            password="password"
            driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
            url="someurl"
            maxTotal="3"
            maxIdle="3" />

</Context>
```

And below is the JUnit code:

```
@Override
protected TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() {
    return new GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory();
}

@Override
protected DeploymentContext configureDeployment(){
    return ServletDeploymentContext
            .forServlet(new ServletContainer( new ResourceConfig( MyResource.class )
                    .packages("provider_package") ) )
            .contextParam("contextConfigLocation", "/META-INF/context.xml")
            .initParam(ServerProperties.PROVIDER_PACKAGES, "provider_package")
            .build();
}

@Test
public void test () throws Exception 
{   
    String result = target("targetURL")
            .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .get(String.class);

    assertEquals("OK", result);
}
```

When I run the test directly above, it gets into the resource pointed to by "targetURL" just fine. However, in that resource, it attempts to connect to a database so it can GET certain elements. However, it fails when the context lookup occurs. When I manually tests this using Postman to directly touch the URL, it works just fine.

I think it's happening because this deployed servlet is not seeing my context.xml file correctly, or it is not seeing my Tomcat server or something. I'm not sure what the next steps are, and I'm aimlessly Googling at this point. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't that context file for Tomcat? You are trying to use Grizzly for the test. There is no provider for Tomcat, but you can use the [external container](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html#d0e17333). But even then, the context file is only discovered by Tomcat through the war, and the test framework doesn't deploy a war. What you _can_ do with the external provider and Tomcat, is the set that context file configuration into the actual server configuration. That way you don't need to worry about it in your test.

Comment: Either that or just mock out anything that is dependent on the Tomcat functionality